# How seperate hour and datewhen extracting timestimp using hadoop command

Tags: r, regex, datetime

I need to extract files's timestimps using hadoop command :

```
hadoop fs -ls /hdfs/data/adhoc//InterfacePublique-Controle-PUB_1EPSE-201808-PR-20190110-183844-indicateurs-PUB_1EPSE/* | awk '{timestamp= $6 " " $7;print timestamp}'
```

And it works giving

```
"2019-01-10 18:55"
```

But when I used system function like this with removing **quotes** between **$6 $7**

```
x <- "/hdfs/data/adhoc//InterfacePublique-Controle-PUB_1EPSE-201808-PR-20190110-183844-indicateurs-PUB_1EPSE/*"

system(paste0("hadoop fs -ls ",x," | awk '{timestamp= $6  $7;print timestamp}' "),intern =TRUE)
```

which returns :

2019-01-1018:55 . the hour 18 and the day 10 are colled.

Then if I add quotes , in the hadoop expression .

```
system(paste0("hadoop fs -ls ",x," | awk '{timestamp= $6 " " $7;print timestamp}' "),intern =TRUE)
```

It gives an error saying

> unexpected token  $7;print timestamp

How can I resolve this please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract the timestamp using `stringr` and `lubridate`:

```
x <- "/hdfs/data/adhoc//InterfacePublique-Controle-PUB_1EPSE-201808-PR-20190110-183844-indicateurs-PUB_1EPSE/*"

library(lubridate)
library(stringr)

ymd_hms(
  str_extract(x, "(\\d{8}-\\d{6})")
)

[1] "2019-01-10 18:38:44 UTC"
```

Comment: thank you but it doesn' give the exactly time given by hadoop command